# Numerical double integration weighted by a probability distribution function (PDF) in python

Tags: python, math, probability, numerical-methods

I have a problem performing a double definite integral in a function which depend of 2 variables (`q,r`) and has one extra integral in it.
The function I want to weight with a gaussian function is:

`F(q,r)=f(q,r)+int_{0,r}(h(q,r')dr')`

And in must be integrated again to be weighted with the gaussian:

`I(q)=int_{0,inf}(F(q,r)^2*g(r)dr)`

The gaussian `g(r)` is centered in the coordinate `R`.

The main problem as you can observe is that I am mixing arrays with scalars. Using the same method that it is used for the gaussian (`np.ogrid` and sum over the axis) could be a solution, but I don't know how to implement it.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import math as m

R=53.
R0=40.
delta=50.
c=2.
qm, rm = np.ogrid[0.0005:2.0:0.0005, 20:100:500j]

#normalized gauss function
#g(r)
def gauss_grid(r,Rmin,pd):
    def gauss(r,Rmin,pd):
        sigma=1.5
        return (1/sigma)*np.exp(-((r-Rmin)**2)/(2*sigma**2))
    gauss_grid = gauss(r,Rmin,pd)
    #normalization of gaussian
    gauss_grid /= np.sum(gauss_grid)
    return gauss_grid

#spherical function 
#f(q,r) 
def form(q,R):
    return (4/3)*m.pi*3*(np.sin(q*R)-q*R*np.cos(q*R))/(q**3)

#FINAL function
#I(q)
def helfand():
    def F(q,R):
        #integral (0,R) of h(q,r)
        def integral(q,Rmax):
            #h(q,r)
            def integrand(r,q):
                return np.sin(q*r)*(r**2)/(q*r*(1+np.exp(c*(R0-r))))
            return quad(integrand, 0, Rmax, args=(q))[0]
        return (form(q,R)+delta*integral(q,R))**2

    FF_hel=F(qm,rm)
    FF_hel *= gauss_grid(rm,R,pd)
    I=FF_hel.sum(axis=1)
    return I,qm.ravel()

helfand()
```

*UPDATE******

I tried with the scipy.integrate library (with `quad`) and I cannot make it done. It is like it doesn't pass the right argument (`q`) to the next function. Here a very simplified version of what I'm trying:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import quad
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

R=53.
R0=41.
pd=15.
sigma=1.5

def I(q):
    #(function with integral inside) squared
    def FF(q,r):
        def integral_f(q,r):
            def f(r1,q):
                return np.sin(q*r1)
            return quad(f,0,r,args=(q))[0]

        def h(q,r):
            return (r*np.cos(q*r))
        return (h(q,r)+integral_f(q,r))**2

    #gaussian function normalized
    def g(r,R0):
        def gauss(r,R0):
            return (1/sigma)*np.exp(-((r-R0)**2)/(2*sigma**2))
        return gauss(r,R0)/(quad(gauss,0,np.inf,args=(R0))[0])

    #main function to be integrated with gaussian
    def function(r,q):
        return FF(q,r)*g(r,R)

    return quad(function,0,np.inf,args=(q))[0]

q=np.arange(0.001,1.,0.001)
plt.plot(q,I(q))
```

The error says:

> Supplied function does not return a valid float.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a simple 2D rectangular mesh of points that spanned the limits of integration points.  Then I'd prefer Gaussian quadrature over each element to evaluate the integral.  It would mean calling the function, weighted or not, at each integration point, multiplying by the quadrature weight, and summing.

It's similar to 2D quadrilaterial finite elements and evaluating the stiffness matrix by numerical integration.

There are 2D quadrature methods in SciPy.  I'd use that before writing my own.

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.quadrature.html

Comment: As in the edited question, I have been trying this approach but I couldn't make it work yet. Maybe I am doing something wrong with `quad` when passing the arguments...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can compute this with two single integrals.

If you write out the double integral you get two parts:

int_{0,inf}(f(q,r)*g(r)dr)+ int_(0,inf)( int_{0,r}(h(q,r')dr')*g(r)dr)

We can exchange the order of integration in the second to get

int_(0,inf)( int_{r',inf}(g(r)dr) * h(q,r')dr')

The inner integral can be expressed in terms of the complementary
error function.

Comment: This was a really cool idea but it doesn't work for this problem as the function F(q,r) is squared inside the gaussian integral and the rule cannot be applied. I´m trying with scify.integrate.quad now...